# cURL wiyh PHP - connect API REST - Token Bearer

Tags: rest, php-curl

I'm trying to use vadesecure.com REST API via curl. (man: https://cloud-vadesecure-com.translate.goog/help/FR/admin/api/req/events.html?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=fr&_x_tr_hl=fr)

I manage to obtain the authentication token but when I want to make a "POST /eventlog" request I get the following error:

```
{"result":"NOK","error":{"code":1,"trKey":"WRONG_PASSWORD_OR_LOGIN"}}
```

here is my script :

```
$data = array('accountId'=>$accountId, 'pageSize'=>'10', 'pageToGet'=>'0');
$headers = [ 
  'Authorization: Baerer '.$token,
  'Content-type: application/json'
];

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://cloud.vadesecure.com/rest/v3.0/eventlog/list",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_POST => 1,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers
));
$responseTest = curl_exec($curl);
print_r($responseTest);
```

I tried auth in Baerer Token mode to try...

Do you have any idea of my mistake?

THANKS

```
'Authorization: Baerer '.$token,
'Authorization: Baerer $login.':'.$token,
'Authorization: $login.':'.$token,
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the vadesecure API, but the documentation says that you need a `x-vrc-authorization` header for authorization. The value of the header is something like `LOGIN:TOKEN` (you will see this in the docs). So no `Authorization` header is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Indeed in the documentation it is explained that x-vrc-authorization is required. That's what I tried first, but it doesn't change anything...

Comment: And you are sure that the `LOGIN:TOKEN` value was correct? Did you received a token after login? From my understanding the header should look like `x-vrc-authorization: aleks:nf73rh937c...` where `aleks` is the login value you used in the `/login` endpoint. In general: If you are not sure how your request looks like, you can check it using [Responsler](http://www.responsler.com) (just change the url in your script to your hostname from Responsler).